# How to send json data using post method in android?

Tags: android, json, web-services

```
I have Url and parameter "data":
URL: http://www.xxxx.ru/mobile-api-v1/query/
data={«type":1,"body":{"sortType":0,"categoryId":0,"count":50,"authorId":0,"lastId":0}}
```

How to add key "data="? Now error "Wrong request"

Comment: `data` is your `JSONObject`. So you need to put your all values in `JSONObject` and post that json object in a raw data format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this :

```
InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data","your data"));
            Log.e("",String.valueOf(nameValuePairs));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        try{
            if(is != null){
                result = convertInputStreamToString(is);
                Log.e("result", result);
            }else{
                result = "Did not work!";
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
```

//this is print your response into String from server

```
 public void String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            String result = "";
            try {
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    result += line;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Please set up this into method this is way to call post method.